# TCPDF: Get total number of pages / find out if it's the last page

Tags: tcpdf

I don't want page numbers on the first and last pages of my PDF so in my custom footer function I'm trying to compare the current page number to the total number of pages, which isn't working since $this->getAliasNbPages(); returns a string (something like "{ptp)"} which cannot be converted to an integer.

How do I get the total number of pages as an integer or otherwise find out if the current page is the last?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$this->getNumPages();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Reset pointer to the last document page.
 * @param $resetmargins (boolean) if true reset left, right, top margins and Y position.
 * @public
 * @since 2.0.000 (2008-01-04)
 * @see setPage(), getPage(), getNumPages()
 */
           public function lastPage($resetmargins=false) {
              $this->setPage($this->getNumPages(), $resetmargins);
           }


/**
 * Get current document page number.
 * @return int page number
 * @public
 * @since 2.1.000 (2008-01-07)
 * @see setPage(), lastpage(), getNumPages()
 */
           public function getPage() {
              return $this->page;
           }

/**
 * Get the total number of insered pages.
 * @return int number of pages
 * @public
 * @since 2.1.000 (2008-01-07)
 * @see setPage(), getPage(), lastpage()
 */
           public function getNumPages() {
              return $this->numpages;
           }
```

originally from tcpdf.php you can find it all there

Comment: I can't figure out how these functions allow you to identify whether the current page is the LAST page. `PageNo()` will tell you the current page number, but it will **always** equal the value returned from `getNumPages()`

Comment: sorry, its been years since I've tackled this, totally forgotten how I did it, I bet your calling `getNumPages` and `pageNo` inside the same loop, which explains why you get equal numbers,.. I know it's stupid but try to do a simulation, `run dummyLoop(){}; $allpages=getNumPages of dummyLoop; run actualLoop(){if(pageNo()==$allpages){echo"you're in the last page mate!";}}` or something like that